# Converting byte[] to String and back c#

Tags: c#, string, byte

I’m trying to convert a byte[] to a string and back using Encoding.Unicode.
Sometimes Encoding.Unicode is able to convert the byte[] to a string and sometimes the output is != the input.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while(true)
    {
        Int32 random = rnd.Next(10, 20);
        Byte[] inBytes = new Byte[random];
        for(int i = 0; i < random; i++)
            inBytes[i] = (Byte)rnd.Next(0, 9);

        String inBytesString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length);
        Byte[] outBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inBytesString);

        if(inBytes.Length != outBytes.Length)
            throw new Exception("?");
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < inBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                if(inBytes[i] != outBytes[i])
                    throw new Exception("?");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, some random byte arrays won't be valid unicode, so, sometimes this won't work. If you start with a random string and round trip it via a byte array, it will work every time.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use Encoding for that: you must use something like Convert.ToBase64String / Convert.FromBase64String.

Encoding assumes the byte[] is formatted according to specific rules, which are not the case for a random non-string byte[].

To summarise:

An Encoding turns an arbitrary string to/from a formatted byte[]

Base-64 turns an arbitrary byte[] to/from a formatted string

Answer (score 0):

```
you cannot use encoding use base64
```

using `base64` u can safely convert bytes to a string and back

`base64 guaranteed to not to get "invalid" unicode sequences` like:
 first half of a surrogate pair without the second half
use like this:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Comment: strictly speaking, base64 is an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I changed and image to a bit array and then converted it back to a readable string.

```
protected bool isImageCMYK(HttpPostedFile image, Stream fileContent)
    {
            //creating byte array
        byte[] imageToByteArray = new byte[image.ContentLength];

            //filling the byte array
        fileContent.Read(imageToByteArray, 0 , image.ContentLength);

            //convering byte array back to a readable string
        UTF8Encoding byteToString = new UTF8Encoding();
        string imageString = byteToString.GetString(imageToByteArray);

        return imageString.ToLower().Contains("cmyk");
    }
```

here is the edited code which results in an output of "OK"

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                Int32 random = rnd.Next(10, 20);
                Byte[] inBytes = new Byte[random];
                for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
                    inBytes[i] = (Byte)rnd.Next(0, 9);

                UTF8Encoding inBytesString = new UTF8Encoding(); 
                string byteString = inBytesString.GetString(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length);
                //Byte[] outBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inBytesString);
                Byte[] outBytes = inBytesString.GetBytes(byteString);

                if (inBytes.Length != outBytes.Length)
                    throw new Exception("?");
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < inBytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (inBytes[i] != outBytes[i])
                            throw new Exception("?");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            }
```

Comment: If the incoming data is binary data (rather than UTF8 data), this is not a valid implementation. This is *only* correct **if** the data is UTF-8 text (or ASCII text).

Comment: Right so if you are using integers like above you should be fine right?

Comment: Integers how? Strings of integer values? integers encoded into binary? If so, what encoding? 4-byte LE? 4-byte BE? "varint"? Something else?

Comment: read it wrong but I edited my code using the example and received identical byte arrays

Comment: yes, but that is coincidence because the single-byte values 0-9 *happen* to all be valid in UTF-8. Now try round-tripping the three bytes (hex) ff ff ff. Or just a single (hex) ff.